# Should we change the "word-usage" tag to "usage"?

Tags: discusión, etiquetas

In [an answer to another meta question](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/148/54), hippietrail said:

> For instance I strongly feel most tags including "word" are bad since they don't allow for idioms, set phrases, and other things we might think of as words but which are actually two or more words separated by spaces (echar de menos, nada que ver, etc). It's better to use "term" or just to leave out this part. Instead of "word usage" have either "term usage" or just "usage".

I was thinking about this, and I think that makes a lot of sense. It doesn't make sense to me for tags to always be differentiating between a single word, or a few words, or a phrase. If we want those distinctions (which I'd argue we don't), they should probably be separate tags ([word](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word), [compound-word](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compound-word), [phrase](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phrase), etc.) rather than prefixes to many other tags.

Our [word-usage](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-usage) tag is currently the 4th most used on the site, but the way it's named, it only applies to words. I'd propose renaming it to [usage](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usage), so we can use it for usage questions about phrases or idioms or sentences too.

Comment: Since voting on the question for proposals such as this is ambiguous (am I voting on whether the question should be asked, or am I voting on whether I support the OP's stance?) I'm going to add an answer purely for gathering votes.

Comment: @hippietrail: Good call, thanks.

Comment: @hippietrail what about [tag:word-choice] ?

Comment: @Joze: I think that should be a separate proposal and meta question.

Answer (score 5):

Vote **UP** if you think we should rename the [word-usage](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-usage) tag to [usage](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usage).

Vote **DOWN** if you think we should keep the [word-usage](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-usage) tag.

(If you wish instead to propose another solution perhaps add another answer like this one that can be voted up/down, or just add a comment.)

Answer (score 1):

After thinking about it more, it seems that *all* questions on Spanish Language & **Usage** relate somehow to usage of the language, and this tag would be rather broad.

Vote this answer **UP** if you think the [word-usage](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-usage) and [usage](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usage) tags should be blacklisted.

Vote this answer **DOWN** if you think at least one of them should be kept.

Comment: Actually I think that's partly true. While there is a usage angle on many many questions, there are some where it's not really a factor, like spelling and pronunciation questions. And there are some that are truly characterised by usage and not really by other things. I think it should be used very judiciously and removed by the mods from most questions.