# What should we do with the meanings-definitions tag?

Tags: discusión, etiquetas, sinónimos-de-etiquetas

A [previous meta question](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146/proposal-regarding-meanings-definitions-tag) didn't really go anywhere, so I thought I'd try a more targeted question now that our traffic numbers are starting to rise again.

What should we do with the [meanings-definitions](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meanings-definitions) tag? Make a separate answer for each suggestion. Vote each answer up or down based on whether you agree with it or not.

Answer (score 2):

The canonical tag should be [meaning](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning), with synonyms of [meanings](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meanings), [definition](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/definition), [definitions](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/definitions), just like it is on English Language & Usage.

While *meaning* and *definition* aren't exactly the same, they're close enough to justify being categorized together in a single tag. *Meaning* is slightly more broad than *definition*, so it should be the main tag name.

I'm less committed to whether it should be [meaning](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning) or [meanings](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meanings). The StackExchange recommendation (as far as I know) is that tag names should generally be plural, but I feel like I see *meaning* as more of a general concept than a distinct thing that there are many of, and I think [meaning](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning) would be more natural (as in other cases like the existing [translation](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation), [word-choice](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-choice), [greeting](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/greeting), [gender](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gender), etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Well I disagree, first that the previous question got anywhere (as we ended up with a new tag and dealt with the others) and second that this tag should be changed to only meanings with synonyms.

It's not that I am against synonyms but that I am for simplicity. [meanings-definitions](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meanings-definitions) is quite clear, we don't really need to make separate tags to distinguish a word difference that in the end won't make a difference in the understanding of the question for it to be answered. A meaning and a definition are often closely related, and if it is the case that they are not, the answer will explain it. EL&U works differently, and I think it fairly complicated compared to how SL&U has been working for this time.

As you said, they are close enough to justify being categorized in a single tag. In the end this question is only of shortening the tag name. IMHO, I don't see the benefit or why should we bother. Instead of messing with synonyms etc..

Comment: I guess the main reason I'm pushing for this is because `meanings-definitions` sounds awkward and unwieldy to me. Can you point to any other tag on any SE site that has two plural nouns joined together like that?

Comment: It's just a tag, it's not a sentence. We have many similar on travel.SE but we always put an `-and-` between to join them. This seems purely down to taste/style though.